# Legends with correct color in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot lines individually so that I can control the color and shape of each line. If I specify the colors outside `aes()`, I would get the right colors, but lose the legend.

Why are the lines not getting the right color when defined inside `aes()`? I do not want to use `gather` or `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

FakeData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
                                  to = as.Date("2020-01-31"), 
                                  by = "days"),
                       Level = runif(31, 0, 30), 
                       Flow = runif(31, 1,10),
                       PCP = runif(31, 0,25), 
                       MeanT = runif(31, 1, 30))
ggplot(data = FakeData, aes(x = Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Level, col = "black"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = Flow, col = "blue"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = PCP, col = "red"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = MeanT, col = "grey"))
```

[image]

Comment: Just add `+ scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")` to your code. The identity scale tells ggplot that you want to use the actual values specified in the aesthetic mapping for line colour (rather than treat them as categorical variables), and `guide = "legend"` tells ggplot that you still want a legend to be produced in this case (by default, identity scales don't show legends).

Comment: Also, you can control the colour & line type (line doesn't have a shape parameter in ggplot) with reshaped tidy data as well. Specifying each line in its own geom is really not the intended way, though it does work.

Comment: Thanks @Z.Lin that was very helpful. Is there away to change the name of the `legends`. For example, instead of having a line `labelled` as `c("black", "blue","red") `in the `legend`, i would like to `rename` it to something like `c("MinT","MaxT","Prec")`

Comment: Sure, you can add something like `labels = c("red" = "A", "grey" = "B", "blue" = "C", "black" = "D")` (basically a named vector) to `scale_color_identity()`. Do note though that this approach can get quite convoluted, & you may find it more efficient to go the tidy route after a while.

Comment: No worries, i got it. I just needed to add `label = c("MinT","MaxT","Prec")` in there.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

FakeData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-01-31"), by = "days"),
                       Level = runif(31, 0, 30), Flow = runif(31, 1,10),
                       PCP = runif(31, 0,25), MeanT = runif(31, 1, 30))
#Melt data
Meltdata <- reshape2::melt(FakeData,id.vars='Date')
#Plot
ggplot(data = Meltdata, aes(x = Date,y=value,color=variable,group=variable))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue","red","grey"))
```

[image]